# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use empty array elements in arrays in CENSORED on line 180

Tags: php, arrays, fatal-error

I was searching on stackoverflow about my problem but I didn't found any good answer.

I have this problem: When I try to run my code

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use empty array elements in arrays in
>   CENSORED on line 180

I receive this error.

This is my array:

```
        $text = [
            'first' => $getTrans($lang, 'reloading_first')."\n",
            'second' => "\n".$getTrans($lang, 'reloading_users_getting')."\n",
            'terzo' => "‎  ".$getTrans($lang, 'reloading_users_getting')." ",
            'quarto'=> "‎  ".$getTrans($lang, 'reloading_admins_getting')." ",,
            'quinto' => "\n".$getTrans($lang, 'reloading_elaborating_list')."\n", ];
```

The line 180 is this:

> 'first' => $getTrans($lang, 'reloading_first')."\n",

Whereas `$getTrans` looks like this:

```
$getTrans = function($lang, $identifier) { 
    global $database; 
    $mammt = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM translations WHERE language=? AND code=?"); 
    $mammt->execute([$lang, $identifier]);
    $trans = $mammt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['translation'];
    if($trans == NULL){ 
        $mammt->execute(['italian', $identifier]);
        $trans = $mammt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['translation'];
    }
    return $trans;
};
```

Comment: Can you show what's in the `$getTrans()` function, and the value of `$lang`?

Comment: Sure, wait a moment please.

Comment: $lang = $database->prepare("SELECT lang FROM groups WHERE chat_id=?");
$lang->execute([$chat_id]);
$lang = $lang->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['lang'];

Comment: $getTrans = function($lang, $identifier)
    {
        global $database;
        $mammt = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM translations WHERE language=? AND code=?");
        $mammt->execute([$lang, $identifier]);
        $trans = $mammt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['translation'];
        if($trans == NULL){
            $mammt->execute(['italian', $identifier]);
            $trans = $mammt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['translation'];
        }
        return $trans;
    };

Comment: I might rather expect that at the `,,`.

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_ ...

Comment: Sorry deceze. I didn't see that. I'm so sorry. Thank you for the help

Comment: Yes, sorry arkascha.

Comment: Just a suggestion: avoid using the same variable for different things. Using `$lang` as the PDO statement and as the result of fetching from the query is confusing.

Comment: The error is because of `,,` at the end of the `quarto` line, it should just be a single `,`.